# Unnecessary packages on my ubuntu VPS server from host. Could I do a diff with standard ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The ubuntu setup & packages that I got on my VPS from my host provider seems to be quite different from default Ubuntu server minimal edition. For e.g. I could see some not so necessary packages like samba, procmail, sound-theme-freedesktop, bluez & many others, have been installed by default !? In a minimal server installation, does they make sense at all !?

Is there any way I could compare the ubuntu I got from the host with the standard Offical ubuntu ? Some way could I diff my setup with the standard ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall` will show you which packages are installed on your host.  You can save the results to a file, and compare them to the results from the same command run on whatever host you want to compare to - say a standard Ubuntu server install in a VM.

Comment: Thanks! Can't I do a fresh ubuntu install from within my VPS, as I do release-upgrade (as my host does agree to provide a real minimal version) very soon ? Otherwise is there any way to reset the ubuntu to default standard ubuntu server packages ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only solution for this is to install a "standard" ubuntu and make the diff by yourself. It can be done easily with `dpkg --get-selections` without any arguments. It will list all the installed packages.